# Mysql server version for the riGht syntax to use near '",2016-01-13','2016-01-14')' at line 1

Tags: mysql

```
Private Sub btnIssue_Click (sender As System.Object, e As Syste.EventArgs) Handles btnIssue_Click

  Try
   Dim dbquery As String = "insert into tblIssued
            values (" & cmbBookId.SelectedText & ",' " &
                             cmbIssueto.SelectedText & " ',' " &
                             txtIssuedDate.Text & " ',' " &
                             datepickerduedate.Text & " ' ) " 
   Dim dbConnection As New MysqlConnection(dbconstring)
   Dim dbCmd As New MySqlCommand(dbquery,dbCOnnection)
   Dim dbReader As MySqlDataReader
   dbConnection.Open()
   dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader()
   MsgBox("Issued")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the column name as well like

```
insert into tblIssued(col1,col2,col3,col4)
values(value1,value2,value3,value4)
```

So in your case it would be like

```
Dim query As String = "insert into tblIssued(Bookid,Idno,Issuedate,Duedate)    
                values (@Bookid,@Idno,@Issuedate,@Duedate)"
Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
command.Parameters.Add("@Bookid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.toInt32(cmbBookId.SelectedText)
command.Parameters.Add("@Idno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.toInt32(cmbIssueto.Text)
command.Parameters.Add("@Issuedate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = txtIssuedDate.Text
command.Parameters.Add("@Duedate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = datepickerduedate.Text
```

Comment: my columns are Bookid,Idno,Issuedate,Duedate

Comment: @RaulTripathi yes .. i used textfield in txtissueddate which generate the currentdate upon load and datepicker for the txtduedate . and i cant insert it into database asking for the right syntax .

Comment: @BrianKyleGalvan:- Updated my answer. Please check now

Comment: @BrianKyleGalvan:- At which line it is showing the error?

Comment: nothinG . just that statement " The input string was not in a correct format " –